# Embedding React static site (create react app) in a website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a react app (created using create-react-app) and generated build (using react-scripts, npm run build).

Build folder has static site (with single index.html, js file and media) which is deployed on a domain (domain1.com).

On domain2.com there is a web app already running. Now I want to embed domain1.com in domain2.com.

**What I tried:**

Inside domain2.com I added `<div id="root"></div>`

loaded necessary scripts and css file from domain1.com

**What it outputs:**

It rendered html, css and all necessary icons but none of the functionality is working. Click is not triggered and no error message shown.

**What is expected:**

It should work fine in domain2.com as it works in domain1.com

**I don't want to use iframe or object (even they worked well).**

Please help me in achieving this.
Thank-you.

Comment: Does domain2 already have a react app?

Comment: No, but it doesn't matter as all the necessary react scripts are already built and loaded in domain2.

Comment: I meant, are both react apps expecting to be on id="root"

Comment: no, its php application which has vue. I also tried on a empty new html page.